# Trouble with UNIX pipes

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, stdout, stdin

So I have some ruby code that loops putting strings to stdout using `puts` then sleeps using `sleep`.  I then have some node.js code that listens on stdin for data events and simply logs what it gets from stdin.

If I run `echo 'something' | node my_code.js` I'll see something, but if I run `ruby my_code.rb | node my_code.js` I don't see anything.

Am I not able to redirect the stdout from the ruby code to stdin of the node.js code using a UNIX pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be very little difference between the two, and the Ruby code should be fine.

However, you are spotting some problems.  What happens if you run the Ruby through `tee`?

```
ruby my_code.rb | tee file
```

Do you see the output? If not, start investigating your Ruby code.  (Does it work when you run it without piping its output?). If you do see the output as you expect, does the Ruby program stop (exit)? Do you get your command line prompt back?

If there's nothing anomalous with the Ruby, what happens with the JavaScript when you pipe a multiline file to it:

```
cat my_code.rb | node my_code.js
```

I expect one of these scenarios to provide you with something to chase.

Comment: Piping to `tee file` doesn't produce anything to stdout or within the file.  The ruby code is in a continuous loop and does not exit.  Is that a requirement for piping?

Comment: Well, it the Ruby code doesn't produce anything on a pipe, then there's no way your JavaScript is going to get any information to read from the pipe.  What is your Ruby code doing?  What does it do when you run it without any redirection on its output?  Does it write to standard output at all?  If it doesn't write to standard output, then piping the output is not going to work.

Comment: It prints to stdout just fine.  the code is basically:
`loop { puts Random.rand; sleep 2 }`

Comment: Buffering...when the output goes to a pipe, it is no longer line buffered, so it will take a long time before the buffer fills and the information is flushed to the pipe. Work out how to turn on line buffering on the standard output in Ruby. Does Ruby support sub-second sleeps? If so, replace the `sleep 2` with, say, `sleep 0.1`. Then run the script to `tee /dev/null` and watch how you get a spurt of numbers after a few seconds, then another spurt a few seconds later. If Ruby doesn't have sub-second sleeps, use a busy-loop instead — the analogue of `for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);` in C.

Comment: Thanks for helping me debug this Jonathan, I appreciate it.  Buffering was indeed the issue; I fixed it so the code is now (simplified): `loop { puts Random.rand; $stdout.flush; sleep 2 }`
Can you explain why output is buffered between piped processes?

Comment: Efficiency...when the output isn't to a terminal, it usually doesn't matter if the output is saved up until there is a buffer full — except in situations like this where it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ruby my_code.rb | awk '{print;fflush()}' | node my_code.js
```

Or this:

```
ruby my_code.rb | grep --line-buffer '.*' | node my_code.js
```

Comment: No beans. :(  Thanks for trying to help though!